# Is it possible to set limit in multiple selection dropdown list?

Tags: php, multi-select

I am using a multiple selection drop-down list in my site.This is working properly and we can select more than one options from that list.But I want select only 3 options from that list.Is it possible to set limit for that??

I am using the code from http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/03/20/492/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use **jQuery** and following **click** function, it will help

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#slectboxid option').click(function() 
    {
        var items = $(this).parent().val();
        if (items.length > 3) {
                       alert("You can only select 3 values at a time");
           $(this).removeAttr("selected");
        }
    });
   });
```

**Edit**: use `.prop()` instead of `.removeAttr()`,`.removeAttr()` is deprecated in newest jQuery libraries

Comment: I would go for the jQuery solution too for the better user experience, but don't forget to validate in PHP (if javascript is disabled)

Comment: yeah, the server side validation is a must. i agree with you mr.claarman

Answer (score 3):

In `formsubmit.php` change line 3 with the following line :

```
if (isset($options) && count($options) == 3) {
```

Then modify line 26 with the following :

```
echo 'Please select exactly 3 options';
```