# Put limit on multi selection box html in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, joomla

I am woking on Joomla CMS. I want to add limit on this multiple selection box using javascript please help me to do this. I am creating my list by using the following code:

```
<div class="controls" >
<?php 
    $attribs = "class='input-xxlarge required' name='selection[]' id='selection[]' onchange='Notify();' size='5' multiple='multiple' ";
    echo $select->getSelectCategoryTree('id_category[]', explode(',', $this->row->id_category), '', $attribs, '', true); 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: here is the code  <div class="controls" >
    <?php 
    $attribs = "class='input-xxlarge required' name='selection[]' id='selection[]' onchange='Notify();' size='5' multiple='multiple' ";
    echo $select->getSelectCategoryTree('id_category[]', explode(',', $this->row->id_category), '', $attribs, '', true); ?>
   </div>

Comment: Your comment seems to be unecessary because the code is present in the question.
Could you please add a tag to precise which version of Joomla you are working on ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the joomla specifics. See this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10410212/2780063). In any case if you run into conflicts replace `$` with `jQuery`