# How can I limit the number of options a user can select from a drop down menu using HTML?

Tags: html

I'm using the code found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple) to create a drop down menu from which users can select multiple options.

How can I change this code so that only a maximum of 3 options can be selected? Can this be done by editing only the HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set limit in multiple selection dropdown list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410169/is-it-possible-to-set-limit-in-multiple-selection-dropdown-list)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did look at that before posting this question, but I was hoping that there would be a way to do this using only HTML - rather than php or js

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no possibility to do that only using HTML5.
You can try to use a little bit of JavaScript and/or jQuery. Have a look at this link: http://loudev.com. Or you can also use some simple jQuery code like:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    if($("select option:selected").length > 3) {
        // your code...
    }
});
```

If you prefer to use only HTML5 the best option is write a checkbox instead of a select so the user can choose more values.

Answer (score -1):

use check box, if you want to select multiple options

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
```